# eclipse-how to create project from existing file structure?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to figure this out and having problems.

I have several projects (not eclipse projects but regular php files, etc) that are in

```
d:xampp/htdocs/project_1 
d:xampp/htdocs/project_2
d:xampp/htdocs/project_3
```

etc

Each project has several files under them (zend framework files, etc)

Anyway, I'm trying to figure out how to set the project files as the root in eclipse and just have each project be it's own workspace.  I know how to create a new workspace, but I don't know how to do this when I have an existing project.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a project directly as the root of your workspace. But you can create separate workspaces, each importing just one project:

File > Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace

Then set "Select root directory" to "d:xampp/htdocs". Select your projects. (Usually you don't check "Copy projects into workspace".)